# How to use `SELECT ... INTO` with UNION?

Tags: sql, select

I am having a problem copying into a temporary table from union of two tables.

The code I am using is

```
Select * into #tmp from table1 union table2
```

Comment: Please post your exact problem with code...

Comment: @KanagarajM - I agree more details would be helpful but in this case the code was in the title and has an obvious problem (incorrect syntax). In particular though the OP should confirm RDBMS, I assume SQL Server / Sybase from `#` prefixed temporary tables and `SELECT ... INTO` but if this is not the case they have more issues with the code than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `SELECT` for `table2`

```
SELECT *
INTO   #tmp
FROM   table1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   table2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e68f9/1)

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
select *
into #temp
from (select * from table1
      union
      select * from table2
     ) t;
```